# Why do we need placement new operator?

Tags: c++

I know that we need placement new operator when memory for an object is to be allocated at a specfic memory location.
e.g.

```
int* MemoryBuffer = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
MyClass* Object = new (MemoryBufer) Myclass;
```

Can't we simply do like this

`MyClass* Object = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(MemoryBuffer);`

Object will point to the memory allocated by malloc above. 
Why do we need placement new operator, does it do the same thing or there is any difference?

Comment: do you remember that user defined type can have constuctor?

Comment: The cast just points to uninitialized memory so that's not an alternative.  Keep thinking about it and you'll inevitably find a use for it.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the point that after new, constructor will be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write:

```
    auto MemoryBuffer1 = malloc(sizeof(Myclass)); 
    Myclass *pObject1 = new (MemoryBuffer1) Myclass;

    auto MemoryBuffer2 = malloc(sizeof(Myclass));
    Myclass *pObject2 = reinterpret_cast<Myclass*>(MemoryBuffer2);
```

Then `*pObject1` is a properly constructed object, and the constructor will have been called.  `*pObject2` is just a pointer to a random collection of bytes, and is not a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

The first one (placement new) calls constructor of `MyClass` and second one (reinterpret cast) doesn't.